Usage of "still" and "not yet." Are those two the same in meaning?

I am still getting used to the new system you have introduced.

I am not yet used to the new system you have introduced.


Do those sentences have the same meaning?

They are very similar, with #1 more positive sounding.

Thank you.  now I understand. I think the first sentence means i am trying to understand the new system but i cannot say i am used to it yet.

That may be your intended meaning in some specific context, but getting used to something doesn't actually have any direct connection to understanding something. In any given context you could have full understanding but not be at all used to something, or vice-versa (no understanding at all of something you're completely used to).

Thank you for your kind advice. Actually I don`t know a correct synonym for getting used to . So I used the useful word carelessly. I will keep your advice in mind.

I'm still getting the hang of it means you're still learning how to use it, but I can't think of any similar expression for I don't yet fully understand it. Who knows what "understand" means anyway? You might take a while to get the hang of / get used to driving a diesel car after having previously only ever driven petrol engines. But you might never understand either the chemistry or the technology that make the two so different.

Thanks again, sir. When I want to get used to driving a diesel car or a petrol car, I dont need deep understanding of different mechanisms of both cars.  I just need  knowledge of how to drive both cars. Thats why I should not use the verb understand in the previous comment. I hope I am not missing something you want to say .

, I want to put check mark on this question because I think Im kind of getting answered by posted comments, but I dont know how to put check mark before receiving an answer. So what shouid I do?

Yes, they have the same meaning.
If you are 'still getting used to' something, you have not finished the process of becoming completely familiar with it. So it is also correct to say that you are not yet used to it.
